# Which ImageNet classes is PyTorch trained on?

Tags: python, pytorch

PyTorch lets you download pre-trained models for classification [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#classification), but it's not clear how to go from the output tensor of probabilities back to the actual class labels. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/imagenet-classes/4923
https://www.learnopencv.com/pytorch-for-beginners-image-classification-using-pre-trained-models/

You need to download `imagenet_classes.txt`